# using "OR" and "HAVING SUM" Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

this is my fiddle :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=71b1fd5d8e222ab1c51ace8d1af4c94f

```
CREATE TABLE order_match(ID int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
quantity decimal(10,2), createdAt date NOT NULL, order_status_id int(10) NOT NULL,
createdby int(11), code_order varchar(20) NOT NULL);



insert into order_match values
(1, 0.2, '2020-02-02', 6, 01, 0001),
(2, 1, '2020-02-03', 7, 02, 0002),
(3, 1.3, '2020-02-04', 7, 03, 0003),
(4, 1.4, '2020-02-08', 5, 08, 0004),
(5, 1.2, '2020-02-05', 8, 04, 0005),
(6, 1.4, '2020-03-01', 8, 05, 0006),
(7, 0.23, '2020-01-01', 8, 03, 0007),
(8, 2.3, '2020-02-07', 8, 04, 0009);
```

and then this is my table

```
select order_status_id, createdby, createdAt from order_match;

    +-----------------+-----------+------------+
    | order_status_id | createdby | createdAt  |
    +-----------------+-----------+------------+
    |               6 |         1 | 2020-02-02 |
    |               7 |         2 | 2020-02-03 |
    |               7 |         3 | 2020-02-04 |
    |               5 |         8 | 2020-02-08 |
    |               8 |         4 | 2020-02-05 |
    |               8 |         5 | 2020-03-01 |
    |               8 |         3 | 2020-01-01 |
    +-----------------+-----------+------------+
```

order_status_id are the status of transaction, "7" means no approval transaction, else are approval, createdby are the id of users who doing transaction, and createdAt are the date of transaction happen.

so i want to find out the repeat users who doing transaction in between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-28', repeat users are the users who doing approval transaction before '2020-02-28' and atleast doing 1 more approval transaction again in date range ('2020-02-01' until '2020-02-28')

based on the explanation i used this query :

```
SELECT s1.createdby
               FROM order_match s1
               WHERE s1.order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
               GROUP BY s1.createdby
               HAVING SUM(s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-28')
                  AND SUM(s1.createdAt <= '2020-02-28') > 1
                  OR exists (select 1 from order_match s1 where 
                              s1.createdAt < '2020-02-01'
                              and s1.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8));
```

from that query, the result was this :

```
+-----------+
| createdby |
+-----------+
|         1 |
|         3 |
|         4 |
|         5 |
|         8 |
+-----------+
```

and the expected results based on the data and explanation was  like this :

```
+-----------+
| createdby |
+-----------+
| null      |
+-----------+
```

because there's no users who fit with "repeat users" condition. where my wrong at?

Comment: I am baffled by the verbose description - isn't that just the same as 2 or more approved transactions  BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-28' AND I would be very suspicious of aggregating dates

Comment: if the users are doing approval transaction for more than 1 times in date range, then its called repeat users, if only transaction 1 time in date range, but doing transaction BEFORE the date range too, its also called repeat users

Comment: the point is, if the users are doing transaction for more than one times, as long the users are doing approval transaction, and in date range or before date range, its called repeat users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
SELECT createdby
FROM order_match
-- select rows in specified data range
WHERE createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-28'
GROUP BY createdby
-- check that user has more than one transaction which' status is not non-approved
HAVING SUM(order_status_id != 7) > 1 -- or SUM(order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)) > 1
```

> that's why i used or exists to check the users before '2020-02-01'

Sorry, I have understood the task wrongly.

```
SELECT createdby
FROM order_match
GROUP BY createdby
-- check that user has more than one transaction which' status is not non-approved
HAVING SUM(order_status_id != 7) > 1
-- and at least one of them is in specified data range
   AND SUM(order_status_id != 7 AND createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-28')
```

---

> where my wrong at?

In `WHERE IN` - this condition gives TRUE for each `createdby` who has at least one approved transacions, because this transaction checks self in this condition.

Additionally - `s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-28'` overlaps `s1.createdAt <= '2020-02-28'`, so 2nd condition is excess (if 1st is true then 2nd is true too).

Comment: but this code was wrong where createdby(users) has doing approval transaction before '2020-02-01', instead it should be appear because based on the explanation, the users are fit with that condition, check my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e1b5848caaf34118469b4c8fa8c20885, i change the order_status_id from 7 to 6 in createdby = 3. that's why i used or exists to check the users before '2020-02-01'

Comment: @FachryDzaky I see. Updated.

Comment: thankyou very much sir, this is what i want, did you know the difference between having count and having sum in my case?

Comment: @FachryDzaky COUNT count the amount of NOT NULL values, SUM summarizes them. If some condition is FALSE then SUM "ignores" it (plus zero changes nothing) but COUNT counts it (zero is NOT NULL value). If some condition is TRUE then both add 1 to current intermediate value. If the value of an expression is not TRUE/FALSE and NOT NULL then COUNT adds 1 whereas SUM adds expression's value (converted to numeric if it has some another datatype).